# Dsiplaying conversation in Android like iMessage in iOS

Tags: android, message

I'm trying to write an `Android` application that needs to show the conversation between two person. Is it possible to implement it so that it's `UI` looks like `iMessage` in [iOS](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/built-in-apps/messages.html) . On the other hand, is it possible to display the first person's messages on the left, and the second person's messages on the right ?

[image]

My first idea is to use an array of `TextView`, dynamically in Java code, setting their `gravity` to right and left. Is it OK? What about `OutOfMemoryException` ?

Regards .

Answer (score 2):

A ListView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) is going to be your root layout for the Activity. You will have to write your own BaseAdapter or ListAdapter and alternate the gravity of the views in the getView() method.